# Setting css class to field in form depending of it's type

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to manually render login and signup forms in Django.
Here is my code:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}


{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="control">
        {% if form.is_bound %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% render_field field class="nice-looking-field"%}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {% render_field field %}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {% render_field field %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p>{{ field.help_text }}</p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% if form.non_field_errors %}
  <div class="box">
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
      {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

My question: is it possible to check in a loop what type the field has and, depending on the field, assign a specific CSS class?

For example:

1. Field_1 has type text, so we apply css-class-1 to it
2. Field_2 has a checkbox type, so we apply css-class-2 to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the django form that is inherited from modelform to define specific css class to the form fields.

for instance,
models.py file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=254)
    text=models.TextField()
```

forms.py file

```
from . import models 
class PostForm(forms.ModelForms):
    class Meta():
        model=models.Post
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
               'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}), #--->> you can use this textinputclass as the css class in your css file to style the title field of your forms.
                'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'content'})
                }
```

now in your static>css>yourcss.css you can access the class that we defined above as normal css class.

```css
.content{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now. This approach is much better.
Thank you.